# JAVA: Trying to get a list by two objects that I have created but got an error

Tags: java, arrays, list

This is my code, and the errors are in `lstA.add(objPintura); lstB.add(objPintura2);`... in "add":

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListaObj {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<String> lstA = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> lstB = new ArrayList<String>();

        ConceptosLista objPintura = new ConceptosLista("1781", "", "PUERTA TRA.I. PINTURA SUSTITUCION", 407.25, "0", "HYP", 0);
        lstA.add(objPintura);
        ConceptosLista objPintura2 = new ConceptosLista("1781", "", "PUERTA TRA.I. PINTURA SUSTITUCION", 300.20, "0", "HYP", 0);
        lstB.add(objPintura2);


    }

}
```

This is what the error says:

> The method add(String) in the type ArrayList is not applicable
>   for the arguments (ConceptosLista)

And this is also my class:

```
public class ConceptosLista {
    private String posicion;
    private String numeroParte;
    private String descripcion;
    private double monto;
    private String cambioPrecio;
    private String concepto;
    private double montoConvenio;


    public ConceptosLista(String posicion, String numeroParte, String descripcion, double monto, String cambioPrecio,
            String concepto, double montoConvenio) {
        this.posicion = posicion;
        this.numeroParte = numeroParte;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.monto = monto;
        this.cambioPrecio = cambioPrecio;
        this.concepto = concepto;
        this.montoConvenio = montoConvenio;
    }


}
```

I've been trying a lot and haven't had any solution, I think is perhaps the kind of variables I use in my class like **double** .
thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lstA` is a `List<String>`, so it contains `String` objects, not `ConceptosLista` objects. If you want `listA` to contain `ConceptosLista` objects, change it to this:

```
ArrayList<ConceptosLista> lstA = new ArrayList<ConceptosLista>();
```